# How to find the task that has produced particular output?

Tags: sbt

When running `rpm:packageBin` some error messages are printed to the sbt logging.

Is there any way to find out which sub-task is producing that error logging? Can I for example get some kind of trace of executed tasks? Perhaps there's a way to run all tasks serially instead of in parallel and show when each task is started/stopped?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if sbt offers a mode of serial execution of tasks. I doubt that since after all that's the main feature of sbt to fire tasks in parallel.

You could use `debug` to see what's going on under the covers.

```
> help debug
debug

        Sets the global logging level to debug.
        This will be used as the default level for logging from commands, settings, and tasks.
        Any explicit `logLevel` configuration in a project overrides this setting.

--debug

        Sets the global logging level as described above, but does so before any other commands are executed on startup, including project loading.
        This is useful as a startup option:
                * it takes effect before any logging occurs
                * if no other commands are passed, interactive mode is still entered
```

You are also provided `last` command for any failing tasks.

```
> help last
last
        Prints the logging for the previous command, typically at a more verbose level.

last <key>
        Prints the logging associated with the provided key.  The key typically refers to a task (for example, test:compile).  The logging that is displayed is restricted to the logging for that particular task.

        See also 'last-grep'.
```

I wrote a task that throws an exception `throwT` and once executed, sbt catches it and offers `last` for that specific task execution.

```
> throwT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:throwT for the full output.
[error] (*:throwT) java.lang.IllegalStateException: exception
> last *:throwT
java.lang.IllegalStateException: exception
        at $a28d9b4066a1b28105c8$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(C:\dev\sandbox\sbt-sandbox\build.sbt:6)
        at $a28d9b4066a1b28105c8$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(C:\dev\sandbox\sbt-sandbox\build.sbt:5)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:throwT) java.lang.IllegalStateException: exception
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sbt supports this feature out of the box. However for your debug purposes you could create a logger and add it to the `extraLoggers` in your `build.sbt` file.

```
extraLoggers := {
  (key: ScopedKey[_]) => {
    val bl = new BasicLogger() {
       def control(event: ControlEvent.Value, message: => String) { log(Level.Info, message) }
       def logAll(events: Seq[LogEvent]) = events.foreach(log)
       def log(level: Level.Value, message: => String) = println("[ " + Scope.display(key.scope, "") + "] " + message)
       def success(message: => String): Unit = ()
       def trace(t: => Throwable): Unit = ()
    }
    Seq(bl)
  }
}
```

When added it should print scope before each message, which is I believe what you want. You can of course improve it further.